# Camera access for both JS and AIR

Tags: javascript, actionscript, haxe

Flambe is a really neat tool, even though developer dissapeared around march, and the proper camera access is missing (I could move to openFL, but I'm way too deep at the moment). This is my take at creating hybrid camera recorder (webcam for JS and frontal camera for AIR). Note that's early development, missing error handling, and lack of options such as different source coordinates and scaling.

```
package ps.component;

import flambe.Component;
import flambe.Entity;
import flambe.System;
import flambe.display.ImageSprite;
import flambe.display.Texture;

#if air
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.media.Video;
import flash.media.Camera;
#end

#if js
import js.html.Element; 
#end

class CameraAccess extends Component
{
    public var texture:Texture;
    public var sprite:ImageSprite;
    public var width:Int;
    public var height:Int;

    #if air
    private var canvas:BitmapData;
    private var video:Video;
    #end

    #if js
    private var captureStarted:Bool = false;
    private var ctx:Dynamic;
    private var canvas:Element;
    private var video:Element;
    #end

    public function new(?captureWidth:Int, ?captureHeight:Int)
    {
        width = captureWidth == null ? System.stage.width : captureWidth;
        height = captureHeight == null ? System.stage.height : captureHeight;
    }

    override public function onStart()
    {
        texture = flambe.System.renderer.createTexture(width, height);

        #if js
        (untyped navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({
            video: true
        }, function(stream) {
            video = document.createElement('video');
            video.src = URL.createObjectURL(stream);

            canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            canvas.width = width;
            canvas.height = height;

            ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

            video.play();
            video.addEventListener('canplay', function() {
                captureStarted = true;
            }, false);
        }, function(err) {
            trace(err);
        }));
        #end

        #if air
        var camera = Camera.getCamera('1');
        camera.setMode(width, height, 30, true);

        video = new Video(width, height);
        video.attachCamera(camera);
        #end

        sprite = new ImageSprite(texture);
        owner.addChild(new Entity().add(sprite));
    }

    override public function onUpdate(dt:Float)
    {
        #if air
        canvas = new BitmapData(width, height);
        canvas.draw(video);
        #end

        #if js
        if (!captureStarted) return;

        ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480, 0, 0, width, height);
        #end

        texture.graphics.drawTexture(System.renderer.createTextureFromImage(canvas), 0, 0);
    }
}
```